# Jquery gallery: разделение массивов

Tags: jquery, массивы, javascript

Доброго времени суток, учу JS и приёмы работы с jQuery, написал небольшую [простенькую галерею](http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/R9mwb/1/), теперь не могу понять как правильно разделить массив ссылок на картинки, если к примеру требуется на одной странице инициализировать 2 галереи и более. Если инициализировать 1 галерею то все ок, если 2 то начинается бардак загружаются картинки из соседней галереи, как я понял это происходит из за того что в конечном итоге ссылки из разных галерей находятся внутри одного массива, как сделать массив уникальным для каждой галерея пока не понял.

Так же еще мучает вопрос зачем в плагинах писать

> return this или return.this.each()

если кто-то в двух словах может объяснить в чем заключается это chainability  буду весьма признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я немного перефакторил ваш код, но основную логику  оставил:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/kWLJe/

в общем, идея в следующем, я вынес методы за инициализатор плагина (не обязательно, но так основное тело плагина чище, а так-же проще следить за переменными), перенес settings, i и массив alt в `.data()` что позволило мне зная только элемент к которому привязана галерея в любом месте получить доступ к  этим переменным.

основной инициализатор обернул в .each() (надеюсь понятно почему)

по поводу chainability, это нужно, чтобы после вашего плагина можно было через точку написать другие методы объекта jQuery. В общем спрашивайте если будут вопросы.

Домашнее задание - найти способ, чтобы не перечислять инициализатор переменных сохраненных в .data() в каждом методе плагина, при этом не внося объект methods в область видимости fn.cone_gallery().

Comment: Спасибо за помощь , для меня $.data() Пока темный лес, так что буду разбираться что к чему.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/11304/eicto

Comment: это на случай удаления плагина с элемента, кнопка закрытия,оверлэй  и кнопки prev/next общие для всего плагина (если в опциях при инициализации не указано обратное),  поэтому они имеют счетчик сколько галерей на них висит, если счетчик становится < 0, то обработчик удаляется с кнопки.

нашел ещё по ходу одну ошибку, так правильнее -http://jsfiddle.net/kWLJe/5/ (неправильно обрабатывал кнопки next/prev)